# Very slow migrations

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, database-migration, query-performance

I have a (KVM) Debian 8 VM server it's running MySQL 5.5.58 and PHP7.1 locally I have a similar machine (Vagrant VM, Debian 8, VirtualBox). Locally my migrations run < 20 seconds if I dump them into a SQL file and import the SQL file it takes about 2-3 seconds.

However on the (KVM) Debian 8 VM server migrations run between 10-20minutes. I have tried increasing CPU count and RAM to no avail.

There are however two things that greately improve performance but still not really usable:

1. Convert migration files into raw SQL and run that takes about 20-50 seconds.
2. Set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` and run migrations this reduces migration run time down to about 4-5 minutes which is still not usable.

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
sync_binlog = 0
federated = 1
innodb_use_sys_malloc = 0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
query_cache_type = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 768M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

**Filesystem:**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         32G  6.0G   25G  20% /
udev             11M     0   11M   0% /dev
tmpfs           422M   17M  406M   4% /run
tmpfs           1.1G     0  1.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.1G     0  1.1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           211M     0  211M   0% /run/user/2031
```

**What I have tested and checked:**

1. Made sure I'm using same version of everything as locally myqsl, php, composer packages no discrepencies here.
2. Tested VM's disk FIO speeds to make sure there is no bottleneck here tried writing/reading single large file as well as tousands of small files getting high speeds across the board (disk is SSD and healthy).
3. Added extra cores and monitored CPU usage during migration it's pretty small.
4. Timed execution of Laravel `getUp` method from `Migrator`. Specifically timed reading migration file from disk, creating a new class and executing the query all seems to be executing < 1s per migration `used microtime(true)`.
5. Checked mysql slow queries for any slow queries nothing was found, migrations are really very basic `CREATE TABLE` statements.
6. Tried installing MySQL 5.7 there was no improvement.
7. Tried increasing MySQL pool and log RAM size.
8. Made sure I'm using InnoDB.

**Note:** This happens in all ways of using MySQL I tested with MySQL installed on host. I installed docker mysql same issue. I installed vagrant instance and mysql inside that same issue.

This `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_comit` seems to make the most difference indicating I messed up something with mysql just not sure why. **Migrations** each runs as it's own **transaction** seems something is causing wait time here not sure what else to check.

Comment: Are the rows inserted individually?  Or in batches?  The difference is a _factor_ of about 10.

Comment: Unless the migration product does some parallelism, more CPUs will _not_ help.

Comment: Most MySQL performance problems cannot be solved via hardware or tuning.  Let's see samples of the statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your raw SQL most likely has a mess of `INSERT` queries in it.

**Edit** The SQL generated by MySQLDump certainly does have lots of inserts in it. Populating a test dbms is often done from a version-controlled SQL file. [Here's some q&a about doing it in docker](https://forums.docker.com/t/automation-of-container-creation-and-creating-image-with-db-packed/4982/2).

Wrap each series of 100 queries or so (the actual number doesn't matter very much) in  transactions by putting `START TRANSACTION;` at the beginning and `COMMIT;` at the end. That will get rid of the churning that goes with autocommit.  You'll have a SQL file looking something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ...;
... (more inserts)
INSERT ...;    
COMMIT;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ...;
... (more inserts)
INSERT ...;    
COMMIT;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ...;
... (more inserts)
INSERT ...;    
COMMIT;
```

Avoid horsing around with innodb parameters; the defaults are generally pretty good, and only need to be changed for large dynamic loads.

And don't expect your VMs to perform as well as your laptop. The days when servers were faster than laptops are gone (for most of us).

Comment: But this does not really help me as I cannot run with raw sql it defeats the purpose of migrations. The default parameters show little improvement. Vagrant is my local VM and runs without any issue. The host server for the VM is much much better than my local machine pretty much top spec hardware you can get. I gave it more ram and made no difference. I don't expect it to perform the same way but common 10-20min compared to 5-15 seconds locally. : /

Comment: I have done as you suggested as a test and import time was increased drastically.

Comment: More importantly, does each `INSERT` include dozens or hundreds of rows?

Comment: No mostly simple `CREATE TABLE` statements.